# Automatically insert import statement when pasting class name copied from its definition

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I use Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components), version: 2023-03 (4.27.0) Build id: 20230309-1520.

Suppose I have two files in the project: `This.java` and `That.java`, both without errors.

If I open `That.java` and double click on the class name (the string "That") to select it in the line:

```java
public class That {
```

and then copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) then paste it into *This.java* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), then the string `That` is inserted, but a compile error appears, as the class `That` is not imported in that java file. I have to import it manually (either by typing the import statement, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or some other way).

Is there a way to set Eclipse to do this automatically? I'm 99% sure this used to work that way in the past (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> would paste the text `That` and at the same time insert the correct import statement at the top of the Java file)

Comment: 2023-03 is two releases behind. Please upgrade and if the issue persists, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (currently it's not clear to me what is copied from where to where, so please show the code of `This.java` and `That.java` and tell exactly what is copied from where to where).

Comment: @howlger  The string "That" is copied.

Comment: It has to be a bit more than just the simple name `That`, e.g. a field or variable declaration like `That t;` or part of a code like `That t =`, `That.`, etc.

Comment: Aha, I tried to copy a for() block and it does insert the imports alongside when pasting. Is there a way to just paste a class name? I often do: define a new class, copy its name, use (paste) the class in another java file. When I do paste the new class name, the import is not inserted. Did Eclipse never support this?

Comment: I don't think so, but I use code completion for that which also adds the import statement.

Comment: Yes, it does, that is what I do now. I expected to have a way to skip that extra step.